# How to use Slack Incoming Webhooks to send a message to a direct user (from the bot, not through the app creator private channel to that user)?

Tags: slack, slack-api

My username is "Charlie", and I'm the admin of a Slack environtment.

I create my incoming webhook following the steps:
https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks
And I create a bot called "Bot" with all the "write" scopes.

Then, I add a Webhook URL to be able to send direct messages to username "Peter".

When I use the typical curl method to send a test:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Peter receives a message from Bot ... that's ok !!

But I see in my private messages with Peter that notification also.

That's to say, it's like Bot has written to Peter as me ... in my private channel with Peter.

What I want is Bot to write DIRECTLY to Peter, not in my private channel with that person.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, incoming webhooks won't be able to post a DM to a user on behalf of the bot. This type of functionality requires additional permissions and therefore can only be accomplished using a Slack WebAPI methods via a bot token.

To post a DM to a user with a Slack API app you will have to:

1. Add a bot user to your app. The bot token will appear in your OAuth and Permissions page after you install the app.
2. Make a call to the chat.postMessage api method and pass the id for the channel/conversation your want to post to. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage
3. To get a list of all channel and conversations in your workspace including DMs make a call to conversations.list https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list
4. To open a DM with a user you can call conversations.open https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open